# Как узнать что пользователь зажал две кнопки например Qt.Key_Left и Qt.Key_Up для того чтобы картинка двигалась по диагонали

Tags: python, pyqt5, key, qtimer, keypressevent

Как узнать, что пользователь зажал **`две`** кнопки? 
Например: `Qt.Key_Left` и `Qt.Key_Up`, для того, чтобы картинка двигалась по диагонали.

**main.py**

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setFixedSize(700, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Координаты')
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.x = 300
        self.y = 200
        self.show()

    def up(self):
        self.update()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Left:
            self.x -= 5
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Right:
            self.x += 5
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Up:
            self.y -= 5
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Down:
            self.y += 5
        self.up()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.x <= -45:
            self.x = 725
        elif self.x >= 725:
            self.x = -45
        if self.y <= -25:
            self.y = 415
        elif self.y >= 415:
            self.y = -25
        self.qp = QPainter()
        self.qp.begin(self)
        self.drawFlag()
        self.qp.end()

    def drawFlag(self):
        self.qp.setBrush(QColor(150, 75, 0))
        self.qp.drawEllipse(self.x, self.y, 50, 20)
        self.qp.setBrush(QColor(0, 255, 255))
        self.qp.drawEllipse(self.x + 10, self.y - 10, 30, 20)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

Действительно все возможно! 
 Вот вариант управления **4-мя** кнопками: `Qt.Key_Left`, `Qt.Key_Right`, `Qt.Key_Down`, `Qt.Key_Up`

- зажали кнопки  `Key_Left`  и `Key_Down` - катится влево
- зажали кнопки  `Key_Right` и `Key_Down` - катится вправо
- зажали кнопки  `Key_Left`  и `Key_Up`   - поднимается влево
- зажали кнопки  `Key_Right` и `Key_Up`   - поднимается вправо

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer


class Example(QWidget):
    pressedKeys = {
                   Qt.Key_Left: False, 
                   Qt.Key_Right: False,
                   Qt.Key_Down: False, 
                   Qt.Key_Up: False
                  }

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setFixedSize(700, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Координаты')
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.x = 300
        self.y = 200
        self.last_pressed = None 
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setSingleShot(True)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.clear_pressed)

    def clear_pressed(self):
        self.last_pressed = None

    def keyPressEvent(self,event):
        self.pressedKeys[event.key()] = True
        if self.timer.isActive():
            if self.last_pressed == event.key():
                self.timer.stop()
        else:
            self.timer.start(200)
        self.last_pressed = event.key()
        self.keyAction()

    def keyReleaseEvent(self,event):
        self.pressedKeys[event.key()] = False
        self.keyAction()

    def keyAction(self):
        if self.pressedKeys[Qt.Key_Left] and self.pressedKeys[Qt.Key_Down]: 
            self.x -= 5
            self.y += 5
        elif self.pressedKeys[Qt.Key_Right] and self.pressedKeys[Qt.Key_Down]: 
            self.x += 5
            self.y += 5
        elif self.pressedKeys[Qt.Key_Left] and self.pressedKeys[Qt.Key_Up]: 
            self.x -= 5
            self.y -= 5
        elif self.pressedKeys[Qt.Key_Right] and self.pressedKeys[Qt.Key_Up]: 
            self.x += 5
            self.y -= 5
        elif self.pressedKeys[Qt.Key_Left]: 
            self.x -= 5
        elif self.pressedKeys[Qt.Key_Right]: 
            self.x += 5
        elif self.pressedKeys[Qt.Key_Down]: 
            self.y += 5
        elif self.pressedKeys[Qt.Key_Up]:
            self.y -= 5            
        self.update()            

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.x <= -45:
            self.x = 725
        elif self.x >= 725:
            self.x = -45
        if self.y <= -25:
            self.y = 415
        elif self.y >= 415:
            self.y = -25
        self.qp = QPainter()
        self.qp.begin(self)
        self.drawFlag()
        self.qp.end()

    def drawFlag(self):
        self.qp.setBrush(QColor(150, 75, 0))
        self.qp.drawEllipse(self.x, self.y, 50, 20)
        self.qp.setBrush(QColor(0, 255, 255))
        self.qp.drawEllipse(self.x + 10, self.y - 10, 30, 20)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю не мучиться, выберите на клавиатуре 8 клавиш
в удобном для вас месте, под левую или правую руку или под обе руки.

Как вариант под левую руку:

```
Q W E
A S D
 Z X
```

Попробуйте:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setFixedSize(700, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Координаты')
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.x = 300
        self.y = 200
        self.show()

    def up(self):
        self.update()

    '''
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Left:
            self.x -= 5
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Right:
            self.x += 5
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Up:
            self.y -= 5
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Down:
            self.y += 5

        self.up()
    '''
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_A:          # Left
            self.x -= 5
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_D:        # Key_Right
            self.x += 5
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_W:        # Key_Up
            self.y -= 5
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_S:        # Key_Down
            self.y += 5
### +++
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Q:        # Left + Key_Up
            self.x -= 5
            self.y -= 5
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_E:        # Key_Right + Key_Up
            self.x += 5
            self.y -= 5
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Z:        # Left + Key_Down
            self.x -= 5
            self.y += 5
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_X:        # Key_Right + Key_Down
            self.x += 5
            self.y += 5

        self.up()    

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.x <= -45:
            self.x = 725
        elif self.x >= 725:
            self.x = -45
        if self.y <= -25:
            self.y = 415
        elif self.y >= 415:
            self.y = -25
        self.qp = QPainter()
        self.qp.begin(self)
        self.drawFlag()
        self.qp.end()

    def drawFlag(self):
        self.qp.setBrush(QColor(150, 75, 0))
        self.qp.drawEllipse(self.x, self.y, 50, 20)
        self.qp.setBrush(QColor(0, 255, 255))
        self.qp.drawEllipse(self.x + 10, self.y - 10, 30, 20)


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет но я хотел бы чтобы управлялось именно 4 кнопками

Comment: @ThugLife мне кажется, что сделать это  именно 4 кнопками практический не возможно.

Comment: Спасибо, я понял

Answer (score 1):

Я, видимо, поторопился написать, что это невозможно.
Просто мы еще не знаем многих возможностей PyQt.

Мой второй вариант, заключается в том, что мы запускаем метод `up()`
через небольшой промежуток времени.

Но две клавиши надо кликать, зажать их пока у меня не получилось.
Думаю, что должен быть другой подход, чтобы залипшие две клавиши 
можно было обработать.

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setFixedSize(700, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Координаты')
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.x = 300
        self.y = 200
        self.show()

    def up(self):
        self.update()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_A:          # Left
            self.x -= 5
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_D:        # Key_Right
            self.x += 5
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_W:        # Key_Up
            self.y -= 5
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_S:        # Key_Down
            self.y += 5

#        self.up()                                                # ---
        QTimer.singleShot(100, self.up)                           # +++
#        print(f"self.x={self.x}, self.y={self.y}")


    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.x <= -45:
            self.x = 725
        elif self.x >= 725:
            self.x = -45
        if self.y <= -25:
            self.y = 415
        elif self.y >= 415:
            self.y = -25
        self.qp = QPainter()
        self.qp.begin(self)
        self.drawFlag()
        self.qp.end()

    def drawFlag(self):
        self.qp.setBrush(QColor(150, 75, 0))
        self.qp.drawEllipse(self.x, self.y, 50, 20)
        self.qp.setBrush(QColor(0, 255, 255))
        self.qp.drawEllipse(self.x + 10, self.y - 10, 30, 20)


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```